# Can I accept a food delivery addressed to my house?

Tags: fraud, theft, mail

Earlier today the local cookie delivery service knocked on my door with cookies that were already paid for that I did not order.

The guy said it was addressed to my townhouse (eg 555 E Cardboard St). However, tenants sometimes confuse their house number with a unit number and will use my street address for deliveries (eg 555 E Cardboard St #575). I told the guy that I didn't order it, and he said he would call the customer to clarify.

So if someone addresses a cookie delivery to me, am I allowed to keep the cookies? I wouldn't suspect that this would fall into the jurisdiction of mail theft.

One could argue that I believed it was sent as a gift from a family member or friend anonymously and that the cookie company never expected anything in return from me for the delivery (as it was already paid for). I also considered it could fall under unjust enrichment even though I never made an agreement with the company to have cookies delivered.

Comment: There's a big difference between "can" and "should."

Comment: Obviously, I was curious about the legal implications

Comment: They are addressed to a townhouse, not to a person? "However, tenants sometimes confuse their house number with a unit number and will use my street address for deliveries" I'm not quite clear on what you're saying. Do you mean their address is actually  575 E Cardboard St #555 but they write  555 E Cardboard St #575?

Comment: Their address is 575, but put 555 E Cardboard St #575. Not sure how this happens, but I get another street address' junk mail for this reason.

Comment: I would be concerned that the delivery was for "cookies" instead of cookies.

Answer (score 2):

You can argue you believed it was sent as a gift from a family member, but as you told us, that isn't the truth. If you make the delivery man believe the cookies are yours when you clearly know they are not, then you are committing fraud.